# Retain variables when use Guid type

Tags: c#, random

Today, I have problem when create random ID with Guid type in C#.

When I want random ID. And I use:

```
obj.ID = new Guid(txtID.Text);    //ID type Guid
```

But when run program. It automatic generate 1 id random when I swipe card.

I want when swipe card. It will random ID and retain this values until I delete it.

**Edit:**
My english not good. Sorry about that.

Here my code generate Guid and set value to textbox:

```
mReader.CurrentCardIDBlock1 = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
mReader.CurrentCardIDBlock2 = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

txtID.Text = mReader.CurrentCardIDBlock1.ToString();
String strCompont = txtID.Text;

onWriteDataBlock1(strCompont);  //Write data to mifare card in block 1 sector 14
MessageBox.Show("Write data success");
```

If `swipe card 1` > `random id[any value]`. 
Continues `swipe card 1` > `random id[any value]`. => `incorrect`.

I want `swipe card 1` > `random id[value 1]`, if I take card leave RFID reader and put again. 
It until return values is `random id[value 1]`in `card 1` for me.

Swipe `card 2` > `random id[any value]`. `Swipe card 3` > `random id[any value]`. => It's ok.

I think this easy to imagine.
Thanks to @Preston Guillot.

Thank you!!!

Comment: `new Guid(txtID.Text)` does not create a random GUID - it parses the text value as a GUID. `Guid.NewGuid()` creates a new GUID - which it is not "random", from a crypto perspective, but is *unique*.

Comment: Preston is right besides txtID will always be the same...

Comment: Thanks for @PrestonGuillot and @Robert Paulson.

In thread I've create `mReader.CurrentCardIDBlock1 = Guid.NewGuid();` to create a random Guid.

But when I swipe card `n times` and other card it show `n ID` of Guid generate.
I want save ID for 1 card. When swipe new card, It will random other ID to new card.

Comment: There seems to be a pretty big language barrier here - can you post code that illustrates your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Guid.NewGuid() instead explicit instanciation, it will generate 99.9 % unique ID.

Comment: Thanks @Valikhan Akhmedov. I've create like your command. But my problem is question above.